# Add new user to using ASP.NET Membership class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am build webform application using vs2012 express edition.
After configuring the SqlMembership provider to store the users credential to my Sqlserver db, i want to create user user but i got this error:
cannot declare a variable of type 'System.Web.Security.Membership.
I spent amost two hour googling still no resolution. here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security.Membership;
//using Microsoft.AspNet.Membership.OpenAuth;

namespace Practice_project.Account
{
public partial class Register : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //RegisterUser.ContinueDestinationPageUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
    }

   public void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        Membership Create_New_User = Membership.CreateUser(UserName, Password);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try and use another overload of `CreateUser`

```
  MembershipCreateStatus status;
  MembershipUser newuser = Membership.CreateUser(username, password, email, "none", 
        "none", false, out status);
```

Putting "none" for `PasswordQuestion` and `PasswordAnswer` and `false/true` for `IsApproved`

Comment: Thanks @codingbiz, am afraid i did not provide enough detail.Am using asp.net CreateUser control with ID ="Register". I will post the working solution.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the asp page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Register" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="Practice_project.Account.Register" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<hgroup class="title">
    <h1><%: Title %>.</h1>
    <h2>Use the form below to create a new account.</h2>
</hgroup>

<asp:CreateUserWizard runat="server" ID="RegisterUser" ViewStateMode="Disabled" OnCreatedUser="RegisterUser_CreatedUser" BackColor="#E3EAEB" BorderColor="#E6E2D8" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#666666" BorderColor="#E6E2D8" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="0.9em" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="wizardStepPlaceholder" />
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="navigationPlaceholder" />
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ContinueButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#C5BBAF" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="#1C5E55" />
    <CreateUserButtonStyle BackColor="White" BorderColor="#C5BBAF" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="#1C5E55" />
    <TitleTextStyle BackColor="#1C5E55" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <WizardSteps>
        <asp:CreateUserWizardStep runat="server" ID="RegisterUserWizardStep">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <p class="message-info">
                    Passwords are required to be a minimum of <%: Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength %> characters in length.
                </p>

                <p class="validation-summary-errors">
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="ErrorMessage" />
                </p>

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Registration Form</legend>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User name</asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                                CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The user name field is required." />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">Email address</asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Email" TextMode="Email" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Email"
                                CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The email address field is required." />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password</asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Password" TextMode="Password" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                                CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="The password field is required." />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="ConfirmPassword">Confirm password</asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ConfirmPassword" TextMode="Password" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                                 CssClass="field-validation-error" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The confirm password field is required." />
                            <asp:CompareValidator runat="server" ControlToCompare="Password" ControlToValidate="ConfirmPassword"
                                 CssClass="field-validation-error" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="The password and confirmation password do not match." />
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" CommandName="MoveNext" Text="Register" />
                </fieldset>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <CustomNavigationTemplate />
        </asp:CreateUserWizardStep>
```

```
 public void RegisterUser_CreatedUser(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CreateUserProfile(RegisterUser.UserName, RegisterUser.Password);


    }
   private void CreateUserProfile(string username, string password)
   {
       string connect = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["_connection"].ToString();
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connect);
       string insertcommand="Insert into Users"
           +"(Userid,Password)"
           +"Values(@Userid,@Password)";
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertcommand, con);

       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Userid", username);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
       using (con)
       {
           con.Open();
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       }




   }

}
```

Comment: You should be able to use the membership provider to handle this for you unless you are not actually using the ASP.net Membership provider as you stated in the question.

Comment: @chart may you want to check the page

Comment: What am I supposed to be seeing on the page.  I have used this many times you should use the membership providers methods to add new users rather than adding them to the db on your own... unless you are not actually using the membership provider.

Comment: I Know you can use the default temp db, you can as well store it on your own database server.

Comment: It is not the database that is the problem it is that you are not using the membership provider even though you asked how to use the membership provider.

Comment: Sorry, I see this as waste of time. All you needed to is get those values from createUserWizard control and call the Membership.CreateUser like I posted above and supply default values where user did not enter anything. Only if you've configured the Membership provider in the Web.Config. No problem if this your solution is already working, but I feel you'll miss some sync to other membership tables